# How to write a function to autogenerate employee id in a c++ program?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have to do this by creating two classes one is class Person and other one is derived class Employee.

Comment: Read a good [C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) and the documentation of your C++ compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)). Then use a source editor (e.g. [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)...) to write your C++ program. See also [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Comment: It's not clear that you have done _anything_ yet.  So I would treat this question as "teach me how to write my first program in C++, then teach me how to define a class, a function, then write a program for me using this extremely vague specification".  Obviously, the question is far too broad for this site, which aims at helping you with a specific problem you're facing in your existing code.

Answer (score 2):

Hey you must learn first then come to ask a genuine question. Don't be a noob.
But apart from that here is a hint with is which I can help with:

```
class Base{
   private: 
          // Some Parameters here
   public:
         // Write logic here to auto generate employee id
};
class Derived:public Base{
   public:
        // Do something here
};
```

I can help you with this, here's only basics you have to learn so first learn .